# Trying to completely Exit from the MapInfo application?

Tags: mapbasic

I tried the following two things:

```
 include "mapbasic.def"

 Declare Sub Main
 Declare Sub Exit

Sub Main()

    If WindowInfo(WIN_MAPBASIC, WIN_INFO_OPEN) then
        Close Window WIN_MAPBASIC
    End If

 End Sub
```

and

```
 Sub Exit()
    End Program
 End Sub
```

But my MapBasic program does not completely exit from MapInfo (close MapInfo).

Answer (score 4):

Let's start by looking at your two statements:

This statement will close the MapBasic Window:

```
Close Window WIN_MAPBASIC
```

This statement will end your MapBasic application and unload it from memory:

```
End Program
```

If you want to shot down MapInfo Professional, you should run this statement:

```
End MapInfo Interactive
```

The keyword 'Interactive' makes sure that you are giving the user a chance to save what has not already been saved, either changes to a table or settings to a workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Try Run Menu Command 113.
113 = M_FILE_EXIT in menu.def

Comment: Thank you for your Input. I tried inserting this line: Run Menu Command 113, in my Mapbasic program and nothing happens. But when I then tried entering the same line in a very short program (with only a Sub Main (): it works. So it looks like I have a problem with my dialog boxes. I tried the following: Dialog Remove with End Mapinfo but then it gives me a "You can't quit Mapinfo" message.

Comment: You can't exit MapInfo from within the handler of a dialog. You'll have to do this after the Dialog statement. You can for example set a modular variable that you can query when the dialog has gone to see if you should End MapInfo or not